# to versus in front of

Tags: prepositions

> He bloodied his own face to a cheering crowd.
>
> He bloodied his own face in front of a cheering crowd.

Am I right to believe that "to" can be used as a more refined way to say "in front of". Are both sentences somewhat synonymous or am I mistaken?

Comment: The first one might be more idiomatic with "for".

Comment: Also, "to" can mean to the accompaniment of, so maybe "He danced to the crowd's cheers." The bloodying part is hard to imagine, though.